# How to load more than on CSV file in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to make a plot in highcharts, incorporating variables from 2 CSV files. I made an attempt based on these examples: [load multiple csv files (correct order) in one chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918532/load-multiple-csv-files-correct-order-in-one-chart) and [load data in highcharts from 2 different csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053644/load-data-in-highcharts-from-2-different-csv-files) but I can't make it work, nothing appears in the webpage, it's just blank. If you see the error in chrome, throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

I would really apreciate any help you could give me. Here's the code and two sample files I was using:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>2 csv_v3</title>

    <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var c = [];
    var d = []; 
    var e = [];
    var f = [];  


$.get('test1.csv', function (data1) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data1.split('\n');

// Iterate over the lines and add categories or series    
$.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');
            c.push(items[0]);
            d.push(parseFloat(items[1]));

      //    });     

$.get('test2.csv', function (data2) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data2.split('\n');

// Iterate over the lines and add categories or series    
$.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
   var items = line.split(',');
            e.push(items[2]);
            f.push(parseFloat(items[3]));   

        });       




var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            },'Text');

var options = {
              chart: {
                     renderTo: 'chart',
                     zoomType: 'xy',
                     },
              title: {
                     text: ''
                     },
              credits: {
                       enabled: true
                       },
              xAxis: {
                     title: {
                            text: 'Fecha'
                            },
                            categories: e
                            },
              yAxis: {
                     title: {
                            text: 'µg/m³'
                            }
                     },      
              series: [{
                       name: 'Puren',
                       data: d
                       }, {  
                       name: 'Ferroviario',
                       data: f    
                       }],

              };
      });
            </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <!-- 3. Add the container -->
 <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto">         </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

test1.csv

```
Date, Puren
18-07-16 0:00,152
18-07-16 2:00,175
18-07-16 4:00,188
18-07-16 6:00,209
18-07-16 8:00,241
18-07-16 10:00,254
18-07-16 12:00,262
18-07-16 14:00,267
18-07-16 16:00,290
18-07-16 18:00,324
18-07-16 20:00,341
18-07-16 22:00,343
19-07-16 0:00,344
19-07-16 2:00,346
19-07-16 4:00,348
19-07-16 6:00,353
19-07-16 8:00,362
19-07-16 10:00,374
19-07-16 12:00,375
19-07-16 14:00,373
19-07-16 16:00,376
19-07-16 18:00,379
19-07-16 20:00,376
19-07-16 22:00,367
21-07-16 0:00,347
21-07-16 2:00,322
21-07-16 4:00,306
21-07-16 6:00,278
21-07-16 8:00,237
21-07-16 10:00,216
21-07-16 12:00,204
21-07-16 14:00,198
21-07-16 16:00,174
21-07-16 18:00,140
21-07-16 20:00,123
21-07-16 22:00,120
```

test2.csv

```
Date, Ferroviario
19-07-16 0:00,172
19-07-16 2:00,171
19-07-16 4:00,169
19-07-16 6:00,169
19-07-16 8:00,169
19-07-16 10:00,165
19-07-16 12:00,154
19-07-16 14:00,121
19-07-16 16:00,82
19-07-16 18:00,67
19-07-16 20:00,63
19-07-16 22:00,59
21-07-16 0:00,56
21-07-16 2:00,53
21-07-16 4:00,50
21-07-16 6:00,44
21-07-16 8:00,32
21-07-16 10:00,24
21-07-16 12:00,21
21-07-16 14:00,20
21-07-16 16:00,17
21-07-16 18:00,14
21-07-16 20:00,13
21-07-16 22:00,12
22-07-16 0:00,11
22-07-16 2:00,11
22-07-16 4:00,11
22-07-16 6:00,9
22-07-16 8:00,9
22-07-16 10:00,9
22-07-16 12:00,9
22-07-16 14:00,9
22-07-16 16:00,9
22-07-16 18:00,9
22-07-16 20:00,9
22-07-16 22:00,9
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be crating your own CSV parser. Example below:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
  var results = [];
  this.forEach(function(subArray) {
    results.push.apply(results, subArray);
  });

  return results;
};

function csvToData(csv) {
  return csv.split('\n')
    .splice(1)
    .map((line) => line
      .split(',')
      .map((val, i) => {
        if (i === 0) {
          const a = val
            .split(' ')
            .map((s, i) => i === 0 ? s.split('-') : s.split(':')).concatAll().map(s => Number(s))
          return Date.UTC(2000 + a[2], a[1], a[0], a[3], a[4])
        } else {
          return Number(val)
        }
      })
    )
}

const test1_csv = `Date, Puren
18-07-16 0:00,152
18-07-16 2:00,175
18-07-16 4:00,188
18-07-16 6:00,209
18-07-16 8:00,241
18-07-16 10:00,254
18-07-16 12:00,262
18-07-16 14:00,267
18-07-16 16:00,290
18-07-16 18:00,324
18-07-16 20:00,341
18-07-16 22:00,343
19-07-16 0:00,344
19-07-16 2:00,346
19-07-16 4:00,348
19-07-16 6:00,353
19-07-16 8:00,362
19-07-16 10:00,374
19-07-16 12:00,375
19-07-16 14:00,373
19-07-16 16:00,376
19-07-16 18:00,379
19-07-16 20:00,376
19-07-16 22:00,367
21-07-16 0:00,347
21-07-16 2:00,322
21-07-16 4:00,306
21-07-16 6:00,278
21-07-16 8:00,237
21-07-16 10:00,216
21-07-16 12:00,204
21-07-16 14:00,198
21-07-16 16:00,174
21-07-16 18:00,140
21-07-16 20:00,123
21-07-16 22:00,120`
const test2_csv = `Date, Ferroviario
19-07-16 0:00,172
19-07-16 2:00,171
19-07-16 4:00,169
19-07-16 6:00,169
19-07-16 8:00,169
19-07-16 10:00,165
19-07-16 12:00,154
19-07-16 14:00,121
19-07-16 16:00,82
19-07-16 18:00,67
19-07-16 20:00,63
19-07-16 22:00,59
21-07-16 0:00,56
21-07-16 2:00,53
21-07-16 4:00,50
21-07-16 6:00,44
21-07-16 8:00,32
21-07-16 10:00,24
21-07-16 12:00,21
21-07-16 14:00,20
21-07-16 16:00,17
21-07-16 18:00,14
21-07-16 20:00,13
21-07-16 22:00,12
22-07-16 0:00,11
22-07-16 2:00,11
22-07-16 4:00,11
22-07-16 6:00,9
22-07-16 8:00,9
22-07-16 10:00,9
22-07-16 12:00,9
22-07-16 14:00,9
22-07-16 16:00,9
22-07-16 18:00,9
22-07-16 20:00,9
22-07-16 22:00,9`
const data1 = csvToData(test1_csv)
const data2 = csvToData(test2_csv)
const mergedData = [...data1, ...data2]
const options = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    data: mergedData,
    type: 'column'
  }]
}
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);

console.log(data1, data2, mergedData)
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/a9zocb40/

[EDIT] FOR LIVE DATA

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const chart = this
        const data1 = csvToData(test1_csv)
        const data2 = csvToData(test2_csv)
        const mergedData = [...data1, ...data2].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
        console.log(data1, data2, mergedData)
        chart.series[0].setData(mergedData)
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [],
    type: 'column'
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/g8ocqwwr/

Comment: thanks for the help, but I need it to read the csv file without putting the series values inside the script because eventually it's going to be automatized and the csv's are going to be constantly changing